# Fill holes in a binary image Processing Language

Tags: processing

I am newbie in Processing Language, I am doing some basic background subtraction and threshold-ed it. and as usually there are some holes in it. I want to remove holes. As it is possible in Matlab and OpenCV. I am searching for it but failed. Is it possible to fill holes robustly and quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but if you're familiar with OpenCV why not use a Processing library implementation like [this one](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing)?